# Is there any way to use automation to setup Knowledge Data Category?

Tags: knowledge, data-category

Is there any way to use automation to setup Knowledge Data Category?

For a migration from a legacy system, we need to migrate the Data Categories as well and we would prefer an automated way to do this.

However, we can't find any documentation about it and if Data Category record can be inserted by Apex or by API or Dataloader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this can be done my Metadata API

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm

Using Deployment or packaging.

This metadata object is available for unlocked packages
[image]